# Issue on populating C# int list

Tags: c#

This might not be a big deal. What is the big difference of populating a list of int(s) in the following code? For me the first way is using the constructor but I am not getting the point of `new int[]` there. I am totally confused on the second way!

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 });
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 });` [calls constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) with `IEnumerable` parameter.

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Is equal to

```
list2.Add(1);
list2.Add(2);
list2.Add(3);
```

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements
>   `IEnumerable` and has `Add` with the appropriate signature as an instance
>   method or an extension method. The element initializers can be a
>   simple value, an expression or an object initializer. By using a
>   collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to
>   the `Add` method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the
>   calls.

Comment: Thanks Backs but how about First method? what is the point of using `new int[]` there?

Comment: @Behseini it's simple. List has constructor that accepts an ienumerable

Comment: @Behseini, just call `intArray.ToList();`

Comment: `{ 1, 2, 3 }` isn't valid syntax in C# by itself. You have to do `new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }` to declare an array of integers.